# How do I let Symfony FormComponent initialize a DateTime with a very specific format?

Tags: symfony, datetime

So I have a FormType that has a `DateTimeType` field like so:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('startDate', DateTimeType::class, [
            'input' => 'datetime_immutable',
            'input_format' => 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s.uO'
        ])
    ;
}
```

And my hope was that if I would submit a `startDate` that looks like `"2019-01-01T00:00:00.000+0100"`, that the Form component would be able to fill my DTO with a `DateTimeImmutable` object, initialized using the correct format.

However, instead my `startDate` field just always ends up being `null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you try to set the [`format`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#format) ?

Comment: As @qdequippe said you need to specify the expected format using the `format` option. `input_format` is only taken into account if `input` is set to `string` which is not the case here as your input is a `DateTimeImmutable`  object. However, you also need to make sure to set the `widget` option to `single_text` in order to have the `format` option doing something useful.

Comment: @xabbuh when I set `widget` to `single_text` and I set `format` to `Y-m-d` then it does correctly construct a DateTime object from a `Y-m-d` format. However, the same doesn't apply for the more complicated format I'm trying to achieve. Any ideas what may be up with that?

Comment: How did you configured the `format` option for the "more complicated format"?

Comment: I found it. Apparently I should've used the format options from this page: http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the solution in the end was:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('startDate', DateTimeType::class, [
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'input' => 'datetime_immutable',
            'format' => "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX",
        ])
    ;
}
```

Using the format options from this page:

http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime